# php preg_match or preg_replace to keep words (many langs) and ALL emoji, but not special characters

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

In a php string that contains lots of stuff (text, special characters, emoji) I wan to keep words, numbers and any(all) emoji...
*** NOTE : words any langs... chinese, russian, english...

I want to remove stuff like `# @ - + = / \ | !@#$%?&*(){}[]~`\°|¬~<>`

I tried this

```
$string = 'ten=n%7B%7Dt 96 אתה это 的 ten(a)  ten[a] / | \ ten+a ten?allo=olla a,s a.l *f aa*d rr+rr aa-ss as;ss df:aa a's b"s 3@3 a$s a%a a&d ~xzdsad xzd°sad aa\dd hh|ss rr`jj     klo <big>< big> aaa¬dfs';

echo preg_replace('/[^\w*(x{1F600}-\x{1F999})]+/u','',rawurldecode($string));
```

I get 
words, (some) emojies and few characters like * ° ~ {}
most emoji are ok, but some gives me  (the square box)

•• emojies have range like unicode U+1F600  but sometimes with letters U+1F60D  ...

How can I improve `preg_replace` to correct this ?

Comment: Tried `echo preg_replace('/[\p{P}\p{S}]+/u','',rawurldecode($string));`? What is the expected result?

Comment: thanks @wiktor-stribiżew upong looking at your comment, it gave me an other idea. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

after digging deeper, I change my strategy and removing ONLY unwanted stuff.

Gave me more control.

```
preg_replace('/[;\-\\\+:<>°~\/\|!?%$`¬#*()\[\]]/umX','',rawurldecode($string))
```

Comment: or a simple `str_replace(array('*','¬','`','°',..............),'',rawurldecode($string))`